# How to get latest record date in MySQL?

Tags: php

This is my MySQL table:

```
p_id    product_name          description           added_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       headphone               headphone         2012-06-23 10:20:11
2       cdplayer                cdplayer          2012-06-23 12:03:51
3       computerbag            computerbag        2012-06-23 04:10:38
4       lcd                       lcd             2012-06-23 08:40:15
5       monitor                  monitor          2012-06-10 05:11:55
6       mouse                     mouse           2012-06-10 09:12:45
7       lasermouse              lasermouse        2012-06-10 11:54:12
8       keyboard                 keyboard         2012-05-28 07:18:21
9       camera                    camera          2012-05-28 10:20:11
10      charger                   charger         2012-05-28 10:55:33
```

I want my results to look like:

23 Jun

- headphone
- cdplayer
- computerbag
- lcd

10 Jun

- monitor
- mouse
- lasermouse

28 May

- keyboard
- camera
- charger

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, why it didn't work, etc.

Comment: BTW there is a `{}` button in the question editor for code.

Comment: You've stated your requirements. Now show us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the format you want. You have to change a little bit in formatting for example with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect... //Database connection
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT product_name,DATE(added_date) AS only_date FROM YOURTABLENAME ORDER BY DATE(added_date) DESC,p_id ASC");

$currentDate = "";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    if($currentDate != $data->only_date) {
        echo $data->only_date."<br>"; //You have to format this, now it's YYYY-MM-DD
        $currentDate = $data->only_date;
    }
    echo $data->product_name."<br>";
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve all your table values using a mysql statement like so. Assigning the result a variable name.

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

So if we say `$results` is the variable that contains all your table values etc.

Then using PHP. You can loop through all the results

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
  $date =  date('d F', strtotime($result['added_date']));
  $products[$date][] = $result['product_name'];
}
```

Now that we have all the product names grouped by the date, we need to loop through one more time.

```
 foreach($products as $key=>$product)
 {
    echo $key;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($product as $productName)
    {
      echo '<li>' . $productName . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
 }
```

This is the best answer I can give you with the information provided, if you make changes then I will certainly improve this. But this is the basic principle of what needs to be done.

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` group by `added_date` order by p_id");

$current_date="";
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$row_date=explode(" ",$row['added_date']);
if($current_date!=$row_date[0])
{
    if($i!=0){echo"</ul>".date("jS F", strtotime("$row_date[0]"))."<ul>";}
    //$new_date=explode(" ",$row['added_date']);
    $current_date=$row_date[0];
    if($i==0)
    {
    $i++;
    echo "<ul>".date("jS F", strtotime("$row_date[0]"));
    }

    echo "<li>".$row['product_name']."</li>";
}
else
{
    echo "<li>".$row['product_name']."</li>";

}
}
```

Comment: it's not help full for